Is this a doomed statistical problem?
Basically, I have census data (e.g. average income, average age, etc.) from a country in 2015 (census unit level) and in 2020. (I think it might be possible to get the same data from 2010 and potentially in 2025).
I know how each census unit voted in 2013 and in 2018 (i.e. the elections happened in 2013 and in 2018). There are only two parties (Blue and Red).
I want to answer questions of the following nature: As the average income in a census unit decreases, does the census unit change their votes more towards red? As the average age in a census unit decreases (e.g. immigration), does the census unit change their vote more towards blue?
The problem is that I have census data only at two time points and election data at two time points. And these two sets of time points at different from each other. I think some assumption about interpolation will need to be made (e.g. linear change in average age of a unit between census years).
I tried to make a model using the Beta Distribution for the percentage of blue votes in each unit. I then used linear interpolation for the census variables (assuming that these variables only depend on themselves):
$$ x(t) = x(2015) + \frac{t - 2015}{2020 - 2015}(x(2020) - x(2015)) $$
$$ \Delta x_{\text{age},i} = x_{\text{age},i}(2018) - x_{\text{age},i}(2013) $$
$$ \Delta x_{\text{inc},i} = x_{\text{inc},i}(2018) - x_{\text{inc},i}(2013) $$
Then I did this transform for the vote share:
$$ \Delta y_i = y_{i,2018} - y_{i,2013} $$
$$ p_i = \frac{\Delta y_i + 1}{2} $$
Finally, I assembled the final model:
$$ p_i \sim \frac{\Gamma(\phi)}{\Gamma(\mu_i\phi)\Gamma((1-\mu_i)\phi)}p_i^{\mu_i\phi-1}(1-p_i)^{(1-\mu_i)\phi-1} $$
$$ \operatorname{logit}(\mu_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_\text{age}\Delta x_{\text{age},i} + \beta_\text{inc}\Delta x_{\text{inc},i} $$
$$ \operatorname{logit}(\mu_i) = \log\left(\frac{\mu_i}{1-\mu_i}\right) $$
$$ E(p_i) = \mu_i $$
I am very doubtful of this model. I think the interpolation might result in too much uncertainty. I was hoping to hear a professional opinion on this problem... or is it simply a doomed problem?


Whuber's suggestion : Here is my interpretation of what Whuber suggested:

For a given census unit $i$, use census measurements from year $t$ to
predict voting patterns in year $t+3$:
$$ x_{\text{age},i,t} = \text{average age in unit } i \text{ measured
in census year } t $$ $$ x_{\text{inc},i,t} = \text{average income in
 unit } i \text{ measured in census year } t $$ $$ y_{i,t} = \text{vote
 share for blue party in unit } i \text{ in election year } t $$
The change in vote share between elections would then be:
$$ \Delta y_i = y_{i,2018} - y_{i,2013} $$
Transform the variable:
$$ p_i = \frac{\Delta y_i + 1}{2} $$
Define:
$$ \Delta x_{\text{age},i} = x_{\text{age},i,2015} -
 x_{\text{age},i,2010} $$ $$ \Delta x_{\text{inc},i} =
 x_{\text{inc},i,2015} - x_{\text{inc},i,2010} $$
Finally:
$$ p_i \sim \text{Beta}(\mu_i\phi, (1-\mu_i)\phi) $$ $$
 \operatorname{logit}(\mu_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_{\text{age}}\Delta
 x_{\text{age},i} + \beta_{\text{inc}}\Delta x_{\text{inc},i} $$ $$
 \operatorname{logit}(\mu_i) = \log\left(\frac{\mu_i}{1-\mu_i}\right)
 $$ $$ E(p_i) = \mu_i $$

The new interpretation: For a one-unit increase in the difference of average ages between 2015 and 2010 (holding other variables constant), the log-odds of the transformed vote share difference changes by $\beta_{\text{age}}$ units.


Michael Hardy's suggestion: I compared my model with Michael Hardy's suggestion:
My Model:

$$ \Delta y_i = y_{i,2018} - y_{i,2013} $$
$$ p_i = \frac{\Delta y_i + 1}{2} $$
$$ p_i \sim \frac{\Gamma(\phi)}{\Gamma(\mu_i\phi)\Gamma((1-\mu_i)\phi)}p_i^{\mu_i\phi-1}(1-p_i)^{(1-\mu_i)\phi-1} $$
$$ \operatorname{logit}(\mu_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_\text{age}\Delta x_{\text{age},i} + \beta_\text{inc}\Delta x_{\text{inc},i} $$

Michael Hardy:

First transform each vote share to the logit scale: $$ \text{logit}(y_{i,t}) = \log\left(\frac{y_{i,t}}{1-y_{i,t}}\right) $$
Then take the difference of these logit-transformed values: $$ \Delta
 \text{logit}_i = \text{logit}(y_{i,2018}) - \text{logit}(y_{i,2013})
 $$
And model these differences directly with linear regression: $$ \Delta
\text{logit}_i = \beta_0 + \beta_\text{age}\Delta x_{\text{age},i} +
 \beta_\text{inc}\Delta x_{\text{inc},i} + \epsilon_i $$ $$ \epsilon_i
 \sim N(0, \sigma^2) $$


An alternative to interpolation is a simple adjustment of the interpretation; to wit, you could evaluate the relationships between (say) income in 2015 to voting in 2018 or income in 2010 to voting in 2013 or, more generally, to income in year $y$ to voting in year $y+3.$

Thanks ... I will try to translate your idea into mathematical equations...

I am guessing that the index $i$ says which census unit it is and $y_i$ is the proportion of blue votes, but you ought to say that explicitly.

You seem to treat a change in proportion from 10% to 20% as being the same thing as a change from 45% to 55%. I have qualms about that. Maybe using a change in the logit would be better. Also, instead of linearly interpolating with the population, I would just use the known population figures in the non-election years as predictors.

yes that is correct: i is for the census unit and yi is the proportion of blue votes.

can you please explain what kind of change would need to be made for the logit so that (10-20) is different from (45-55)?

Whuber: I updated the question to write what I understood from your comment

Michael Hardy: I made a similar update
